# jQuery Resize function looping strangely

Tags: jquery, function, resize, jquery-ui-accordion

I have jQuery code to make accordion for page content when window width is resized 500px or less.

When I use `jQuery(window).load(function () {` accordion works like it should. But when I use `jQuery(window).resize(function () {` or `jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){` script is acting strangly and it loops (opens and closes accordion content).

I need to use resize function to make accordion work when window size is resized. There should be no need to reload page to get accordion working after resizing.

Here is the code and [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/) example. In JSFIDDLE try resizing Result window to smaller and clicking Content title.

```
jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){

jQuery(function() {
if(jQuery(window).width() <= 500) {


    //ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION   
    jQuery('h3').click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            jQuery('h3').data('slided',false);
            jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');   
            jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
        }
    });

    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    jQuery(".sec").hide();
} else { jQuery(".sec").show(); }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange behavior on a click is because you add a event listener each time the load or resize event is triggered.

You have to move the event binding outside the load/resize event handler.

```
//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('h3').click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            jQuery('h3').data('slided',false);
            jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');   
            jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
        }
    });    
 });

 jQuery(window).on("load resize",function(e){
    if(jQuery(window).width() <= 500) {         
    //HIDE THE DIVS ON PAGE LOAD    
    jQuery(".sec").hide();
 } else {
    jQuery(".sec").show();
 }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/12/)